# Java Hibernate id auto increment

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Hy

I'v a little problem with hibernate on netbeans.
I've a table with an Auto increment id :

```
CREATE TABLE "DVD"
(
    "DVD_ID" INT not null primary key
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    "TITLE" VARCHAR(150),
    "COM" LONG VARCHAR,
 "COVER" VARCHAR(150) 

);
```

But this auto increment is not properly detected with Reverse Engineering.
I get a map file with this :

```
<id name="dvdId" type="int">
    <column name="DVD_ID" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

i've looked on google and on this site ... foud some stuf but i'm still stuck..

i've tried to add ***insert="false" update="false"*** on the map file but i get back :

***Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "insert" must be declared for element type "id".***

Anny help will be pleased

Vincent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the generator class to "identity" if you want an auto-generated value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you well but if you aren't using user input for "id" and you want it to autogenerate and autoincrement, then just change `class="assigned"` to `class="increment"`.